# Почему «под Бородином» менее литературно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, топонимика

> В современном русском языке широко распространены случаи вариативного написания тех или иных слов. Тем не менее в соответствии со строгими литературными нормами, одно из исторических сражений могло происходить:
>
> 1. Под Бородиным
> 2. Под Бородином
> 3. Под деревней Бородино

[*(Источник)*](https://ustaliy.ru/snax_quiz/test-po-russkomu-yazyku/13/)

Пишут, что правильный ответ — № 3. Я не согласен, потому что считаю, что № 2 вполне нормативен. Прав ли я? Корректно ли составлено приведенное задание?

Answer (score 3):

Прав, ещё как прав! Задание - некорректно, ох некорректно!

Культура письменной речи - премногоуважаемый сайт - глаголет:

[несклоняемые варианты <топонимов с окончанием -О> нормативны разве что для профессиональной и устной речи, а в образцовом литературном стиле такие формы необходимо склонять.](http://gramma.ru/SPR/?id=3.2)

Так что склоняем.

Но вариант 1 нам не подходит, смотрим в Письмовнике:

[Как склонять географические названия?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)

> Географические названия на -ов (-ев), -ово (-ево), -ин, **-ино**
>   (-ыно) имеют в творительном падеже окончание -ом, например: Львов –
>   Львовом, Канев – Каневом, Крюково – Крюковом, Камышин – Камышином,
>   **Марьино – Марьином**, Голицыно – Голицыном.

(Выделено мною - как параллель к Бород**ино**.)

А вариант 3 - просто уход от проблемы склонения при помощи добавления родового наименования.

Но:

[существует несколько случаев, когда топонимы на ***-о*** употребляются в неизменяемой форме и в рамках высокого стиля речи:](http://gramma.ru/SPR/?id=3.2)

> когда **род географического названия и родового наименования не
>   совпадает**: *в деревне Босово, на станции Синево, из станицы Лихово.*
>   Здесь слова - родовые наименования женского рода (деревня, станция,
>   станица), но при них названия сохраняют форму среднего; другой пример:
>   *на берегу озера Кафтино, в поселке Синявино, от порта Ванино* - слова - географические названия сохраняют форму именительного падежа, в то время как родовые наименования изменяются по падежам, -

взят из предложенных трёх "наш" случай.

Остался [вариант 2, изучаем](http://kak-pravilno-plus.ru/2015/12/13/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC/):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]